# Mac App Store updated an app, app doesn't know?

Tags: applications, xcode, mac-appstore

A few days ago, I have seen the newly released version of Xcode (6.3) in the updates section of the store, so today I decided to update it.

Updating from 6.2, the process started normally (Xcode was closed during this time) all the way until I could see on launch pad that the download and installation are completed. In the App Store updates section, I can see in recent updates - Xcode 6.3

However, opening Xcode shows me that I'm on version 6.2! As if the update never happened, which means I can't run my projects on iOS 8.3 devices...

Now I know I could uninstall and reinstall, but I'm trying to avoid this painful process..

Do you guys have any idea about what might be happening here?

I found a similar question, unanswered, from Oct' 14' [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152856/xcode-not-updated-after-updating-through-mac-app-store?rq=1)

Comment: Reinstalling isn't exactly painful. Delete the .app from the Applications folder and download it again. All your preferences will be kept.

Comment: I suggest you turn that into an answer so I can accept. Was quick and easy. Thanks.

Comment: I have occasionally found two versions of an app present in two circumstances.  (1) the developer insists on making the version number part of the .app name; (2) The installer puts it in /Applications instead of the directory I prefer to keep the app in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling is a very easy process on OS X Apps. Delete the .app from the Applications folder and download it again. Preferences and data are usually stored in the Library-Folder of your System or User and are therefor left untouched when deleting the .app file.